# Excel refresh macro is not running for one xlsm file on sharepoint location for other files it is running successfully? Any reason

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, interop

I am using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** for opening excel from sharepoint location and running the refresh macro as follows:

```
Workbook wb = default(Workbook);
wb = app.ActiveWorkbook;
wb.Activate();
app.Run("Refresh");
```

For one of the files that i have recently uploaded on sharepoint, the macro is not running, but when I debug the same code locally it works. I am not able to figure out the cause.

Comment: Office documents opened from Sharepoint tend to start in read only mode with macros disabled. Have you double checked security settings aren't causing the problems?

Comment: For other two files that i am saying about starts in read-only mode but still macro runs for that file, but the one file causing the issue.(macro name is also same). BTW how to check security settings

Comment: macro security is enable all macros

Comment: Ah - then I'm not too sure, sorry. You could try adding error logging. (Sorry, last link was VB, you should be able to use normal C# exception handling to log any errors)

Comment: yes thanks !!! @Octopoid